# Makehuman + Rigify: How do you "join" / "unite" loose objects before rigging?

Tags: rigging, rigify, makehuman

Just started out recently with *Blender 2.8* and was trying this out for a side project:


1) I have created a model using Makehuman


2) Imported the model into blender as an .obj and sorted out the textures


3) Separated added elements (e.g. hair, shoes, clothes)

[image: Whole model]

[image: Whole model minus hair]

4. Generated a rig using rigify.


   **How can we join all models into a single mesh for rigging?**
   I've come across answers recommending weight transfer in situations involving armatures. How is that supposed to work with a rig?


   [image: Rigify rig]

Thanks in advance!


**SOME UPDATES**


Tested also, as seen here, by pairing .hbv armature and .obj:

[image: Objects are not connecting with the movement of the main model]


The .obj exported from Makehuman is visible as a single object/layer, yet it has separate components?! How can we merge these components?


No dice with boolean "Union" as well.

[image: Modifier is disabled. Skipping apply.]

[image: 1]

[image: 2]